# Slide View from Top Over the another layout android

Tags: android, animation, layout

I want to slide-in/Slide-out my View from top over the another view. When the top view slide in, the first visible view become fade and if user click outside the top view, it will slide-out again using bottom-to-top animation and first view become completely visible again. For example, you can check the line chat layout, in which user can check the different option by clicking on the top right button in action bar and button become visible over the chat screen.

Comment: do you want `NavigationDrawer` kind of thing ?

Comment: Upto some extent, but it pulls down from top.

Comment: I guess you want a [Depth Page Transformer](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/SlidingDrawer which makes it possible to slide from any side by few lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need:

https://github.com/wunderlist/android-sliding-layer-lib

```
<com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer
    xmlns:slidingLayer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slidingLayer1"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/layer_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/layer_height"
    slidingLayer:shadowDrawable="@drawable/sidebar_shadow"
    slidingLayer:shadowSize="@dimen/shadow_size"
    slidingLayer:offsetDistance="@dimen/offset_distance"
    slidingLayer:previewOffsetDistance="@dimen/preview_offset_distance"
    slidingLayer:stickTo="top|bottom|right|left"
    slidingLayer:changeStateOnTap="true">

</com.wunderlist.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer>
```

You can change the sliding pattern/direction here.

Install this app before you proceed with its integration:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidinglayersample&hl=en

Comment: yes i need the same thing, But i want to close it when user click outside the uper layout. got my point?

Comment: call the dismiss-layer method, when user clicks outside the upper layout. got my point?